# Slug for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I use both pages and blog posts on my site.  Pages get the URL example.org/%postname%/, and based on Permalink settings, posts get the URL example.org/blog/%postname%/.  Perfect.

I have a custom post type used by another group on my site for their web pages.  In registering the post type, I have a rewrite slug for them:
`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'ncfpw'),`
However, their pages are getting the URL
example.org/blog/ncfpw/%postname%/

How can I get rid of "blog" in their URLs?  Somehow it seems Wordpress sees the custom post type as posts, not pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow it seems Wordpress sees the custom post type as posts, not
> pages?

No, but your permalink structure (for the default `post` post type) that you set via the Permalink Settings admin page contains (or starts with) `blog/` and by default, it will also be prepended to permalinks for custom post types, unless the post type sets the [`with_front` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) to `false`.

Therefore,

> How can I get rid of "blog" in their URLs?

Just set the `with_front` to `false`:

```php
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'ncfpw', 'with_front' => false),
```

And then flush the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalink Settings page.